# Extract two specified words from the dataframe and place them in a new column, then delete the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

This is the dataframe:

```
data = {"Company" : [["ConsenSys"] , ["Cognizant"], ["IBM"], ["IBM"], ["Reddit, Inc"], ["Reddit, Inc"], ["IBM"]],
"skills" : [['services', 'scientist technical expertise', 'databases'], ['datacomputing tools experience', 'deep learning models', 'cloud services'], ['quantitative analytical projects', 'financial services', 'field experience'],
['filesystems server architectures', 'systems', 'statistical analysis', 'data analytics', 'workflows', 'aws cloud services'], ['aws services'], ['data mining statistics', 'statistical analysis', 'aws cloud', 'services', 'data discovery', 'visualization'], ['communication skills experience', 'services', 'manufacturing environment', 'sox compliance']]}

dff = pd.DataFrame(data)
dff
```

- I need to create a new column, and I want to start by taking specific
  words out of the skills column.
- The row that does not include those specific words should then be
  deleted.
- Specific words: 'services', 'statistical analysis'

Expected Output:

|  | Company | skills | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [ConsenSys] | [services, scientist technical expertise, databases] | [services] |
| 1 | [IBM] | [filesystems server architectures, systems, statistical analysis, data analytics, workflows, aws cloud services] | [services, statistical analysis] |
| 2 | [Reddit, Inc] | [data mining statistics, statistical analysis, aws cloud, services, data discovery, visualization] | [statistical analysis] |
| 3 | [IBM] | ['communication skills experience', 'services', 'manufacturing environment', 'sox compliance'] | [services] |

I tried quite a lot of code in an effort to extract a specific word from the one that was available on Stack Overflow, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: wrong examlpe. IBM has services and statical analysis both. ['data mining statistics', 'statistical analysis', 'aws cloud', 'services', 'data discovery', 'visualization']

Comment: Thank you so much for bringing that to my attention; I truly appreciate it. I missed that by accident. I edit already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
word = ['services', 'statistical analysis']
s1 = df['skills'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in word if i in x])
```

output(`s1`):

```
0                          [services]
1                                  []
2                                  []
3              [statistical analysis]
4                                  []
5    [services, statistical analysis]
6                          [services]
Name: skills, dtype: object
```

make `s1` to `new_col` and `boolean indexing`

```
df.assign(new_col=s1)[lambda x: x['new_col'].astype('bool')]
```

result:

```
    Company skills  new_col
0   [ConsenSys] [services, scientist technical expertise, data...   [services]
3   [IBM]   [filesystems server architectures, systems, st...   [statistical analysis]
5   [Reddit, Inc]   [data mining statistics, statistical analysis,...   [services, statistical analysis]
6   [IBM]   [communication skills experience, services, ma...   [services]
```

i think you should make more simple example

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda with a list comp

```
words = ["services", "statistical analysis"]
dff["found"] = dff["skills"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(set([i for i in x if i in words])).split(", "))
```

Comment: Maybe add something simple like `dff_new = dff[dff['found'].str.len() > 0]` so that the result is filtered by rows without those words?

Comment: @Frodnar if empty list convert to `bool`, return `False`.